# Are GridFS Java objects thread safe?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I know that Java com.mongodb.Mongo objects are thread safe, but if I use the database returned from it to create a GridFS object, is that GridFS object also thread safe?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, instances of GridFS are also thread safe.